# Emacs "Autoresize.vim" Equivalent

Tags: emacs, vim-plugin

I am trying to make my emacs behave like this vim plugin: where when split between two vertical windows, switching between them makes the current window about 60% of the total width, and the previous window 40%.

```
  .-----------------.
  |          |      |
  |     A    |   B  |
  |          |      |
  .-----------------.
  .-----------------.
  |       |         |
  |   A   |    B    |
  |       |         |
  .-----------------.
```

Here is the vim plugin: [autoresize.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2080)

Does such a thing already exist?

If not, I figure I can use the enlarge-window-horizontally command, but I cannot find the hook that is fired from switching between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [golden-ratio.el](https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el).

I haven't tried it myself, but it does what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's an exact match, and I'm not an emacs wiz by any stretch, but have a look at [Switching Buffers](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers) article from [emacswiki.org](http://emacswiki.org/emacs).

A couple of selections from that page look promising, especially the snippet regarding [Transposing Two Buffers](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers#toc6):

```lisp
(defun transpose-buffers (arg)
  "Transpose the buffers shown in two windows."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((selector (if (>= arg 0) 'next-window 'previous-window)))
    (while (/= arg 0)
      (let ((this-win (window-buffer))
            (next-win (window-buffer (funcall selector))))
        (set-window-buffer (selected-window) next-win)
        (set-window-buffer (funcall selector) this-win)
        (select-window (funcall selector)))
      (setq arg (if (plusp arg) (1- arg) (1+ arg))))))
```